# WPF XAML RadioButton that has hover animation, but keeps hover style when checked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create similar Buttons to the Discords server selection buttons. That being said, they should have a hover animation (change the CornerRadius while hovering), but if you click the RadioButton, the CornerRadius should stay the same even if you dont hover anymore. I have run into a few issues here, where the hover animation doesnt work anymore after a button is checked and unchecked. What am I doing wrong?

I tried adding an ExitAction to the "IsChecked" Trigger, but that just adds an extra animation, and the hover animation does still not work when the RadioButton was checked and unchecked.

This is a visualization of my problem. After the RadioButtons have been checked before the hover animation stops working:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwhOI.jpg

Here are my current Style.Triggers

```
<Style.Triggers>

            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
            </Trigger>

            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
            </Trigger>

            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.CornerRadius)">
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <CornerRadius BottomLeft="40" BottomRight="40" TopLeft="40" TopRight="40"/>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.025">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <CornerRadius BottomLeft="37" BottomRight="37" TopLeft="37" TopRight="37"/>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.05">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <CornerRadius BottomLeft="34" BottomRight="34" TopLeft="34" TopRight="34"/>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.075">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <CornerRadius BottomLeft="31" BottomRight="31" TopLeft="31" TopRight="31"/>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <CornerRadius BottomLeft="28" BottomRight="28" TopLeft="28" TopRight="28"/>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>

                <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.CornerRadius)">
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <CornerRadius BottomLeft="28" BottomRight="28" TopLeft="28" TopRight="28"/>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.025">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <CornerRadius BottomLeft="31" BottomRight="31" TopLeft="31" TopRight="31"/>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.05">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <CornerRadius BottomLeft="34" BottomRight="34" TopLeft="34" TopRight="34"/>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.075">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <CornerRadius BottomLeft="37" BottomRight="37" TopLeft="37" TopRight="37"/>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <CornerRadius BottomLeft="40" BottomRight="40" TopLeft="40" TopRight="40"/>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
            </MultiTrigger>

            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.CornerRadius)">
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <CornerRadius BottomLeft="28" BottomRight="28" TopLeft="28" TopRight="28"/>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>

                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.CornerRadius)">
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <CornerRadius BottomLeft="28" BottomRight="28" TopLeft="28" TopRight="28"/>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.025">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <CornerRadius BottomLeft="31" BottomRight="31" TopLeft="31" TopRight="31"/>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.05">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <CornerRadius BottomLeft="34" BottomRight="34" TopLeft="34" TopRight="34"/>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.075">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <CornerRadius BottomLeft="37" BottomRight="37" TopLeft="37" TopRight="37"/>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <CornerRadius BottomLeft="40" BottomRight="40" TopLeft="40" TopRight="40"/>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>

        </Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: could you show a minimal sample, to reproduce the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trigger logic or conditions to be more precise are wrong. You  missed some important conditions in order to cue the animations properly.

When defining a `Trigger` or `DataTrigger` you will always trigger on the object state.
If the trigger just modifies properties that originally have a valid value in the context of the old state you are generally fine: after the new state transitions back to the previous state, XAML will apply the previous values of the old state implicitly.
For example, if your `Style` configures an element for an *"enabled"* state (`IsEnabled == true`), then defining a `Trigger`/`DataTrigger` for the *"disabled"* state (`IsEnabled == false`) will be enough as the previous state *"enabled"* is well defined and the XAML engine will simply fallback to the previous *"enabled"* state after the *"disabled"* state ends.
But if the *"enabled"* state is not well defined (for example some of the values that are modified by the trigger are not valid or undefined) the *"disabled"* state can't transition back to the previous and undefined state. In this case you would have to explicitly define an additional *"enabled"* `Trigger`/`DataTrigger` to cover that case and to provide valid values so that the transition from *"disabled"* back to *"enabled"* can execute. Setting the animated values to a valid default using a `Style.Setter` is also an alternative to avoid the explicit trigger.

Now in addition, when you use animations you must always keep in mind that the animation does not simply stop when the end value of the animation is reached. Unless the `Storyboard.FillBehavior` is explicitly set to `FillBehavior.Stop` the animation continues in order to hold the value. Otherwise, if the animation stops here, the animated property would be reverted to the original value.
This means in your case the animation of the *"IsChecked"* state trigger is still active - one reason is because you decide to define the `ExitAction`. The `ExitAction` animation remains activated although the state fro the trigger is no longer valid. That's the whole point of the `ExitAction`. The other reason is that there is no state trigger defined that explicitly counteracts for the *"IsChecked"* state `Trigger` in order to implicitly stop it.
In other words the *"IsChecked"* state `Trigger` doesn't properly cue the *"!IsChecked/IsMouseOver"* state `MultiTrigger`.

I generally recommend to use the `VisualStateManager` to handle animation of control states. This ensures that animations properly cue each other.

### Recommended solution using `VisualStateManager`

This is an improved version of your original `Style`.

```xml
<Style x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle"
       TargetType="ToggleButton">
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
          Value="1" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Border x:Name="Border"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
              <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
              <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
              <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
            </VisualStateGroup>

            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness"
                                      To="3" />
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.CornerRadius)">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                          <CornerRadius BottomLeft="28"
                                        BottomRight="28"
                                        TopLeft="28"
                                        TopRight="28" />
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
              <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
              <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition From="Checked"
                                  To="Unchecked">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.CornerRadius)">
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <CornerRadius BottomLeft="28"
                                          BottomRight="28"
                                          TopLeft="28"
                                          TopRight="28" />
                          </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.025">
                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <CornerRadius BottomLeft="31"
                                          BottomRight="31"
                                          TopLeft="31"
                                          TopRight="31" />
                          </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.05">
                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <CornerRadius BottomLeft="34"
                                          BottomRight="34"
                                          TopLeft="34"
                                          TopRight="34" />
                          </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.075">
                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <CornerRadius BottomLeft="37"
                                          BottomRight="37"
                                          TopLeft="37"
                                          TopRight="37" />
                          </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15">
                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <CornerRadius BottomLeft="40"
                                          BottomRight="40"
                                          TopLeft="40"
                                          TopRight="40" />
                          </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualTransition>
              </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

          <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                    Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Cursor"
                    Value="Hand" />
          </Trigger>

          <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                    Value="True">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                    Value="Bottom" />
          </Trigger>

          <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                          Value="True" />
              <Condition Property="IsChecked"
                          Value="False" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
              <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard BeginTime="0:0:0">
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.CornerRadius)">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                          <CornerRadius BottomLeft="40"
                                        BottomRight="40"
                                        TopLeft="40"
                                        TopRight="40" />
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.025">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                          <CornerRadius BottomLeft="37"
                                        BottomRight="37"
                                        TopLeft="37"
                                        TopRight="37" />
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.05">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                          <CornerRadius BottomLeft="34"
                                        BottomRight="34"
                                        TopLeft="34"
                                        TopRight="34" />
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.075">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                          <CornerRadius BottomLeft="31"
                                        BottomRight="31"
                                        TopLeft="31"
                                        TopRight="31" />
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                          <CornerRadius BottomLeft="28"
                                        BottomRight="28"
                                        TopLeft="28"
                                        TopRight="28" />
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>

            <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
              <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.CornerRadius)">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                          <CornerRadius BottomLeft="28"
                                        BottomRight="28"
                                        TopLeft="28"
                                        TopRight="28" />
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.025">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                          <CornerRadius BottomLeft="31"
                                        BottomRight="31"
                                        TopLeft="31"
                                        TopRight="31" />
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.05">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                          <CornerRadius BottomLeft="34"
                                        BottomRight="34"
                                        TopLeft="34"
                                        TopRight="34" />
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.075">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                          <CornerRadius BottomLeft="37"
                                        BottomRight="37"
                                        TopLeft="37"
                                        TopRight="37" />
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                          <CornerRadius BottomLeft="40"
                                        BottomRight="40"
                                        TopLeft="40"
                                        TopRight="40" />
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
            </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
          </MultiTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

### Alternative solution

This solution explicitly stops the `IsChecked` state animation to allow the `MultiTrigger` animation to animate the `Border`. It doesn't modify the originally posted `Style` too much in that it adds only the `Storyboard` management.

```xml
<Style x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle"
       TargetType="ToggleButton">
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
          Value="1" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Border x:Name="Border"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
          <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                    Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Cursor"
                    Value="Hand" />
          </Trigger>

          <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                    Value="True">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                    Value="Bottom" />
          </Trigger>

          <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                          Value="True" />
              <Condition Property="IsChecked"
                          Value="False" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>

              <!-- Stop previous animation that block the targeted property from being animated -->
              <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="EnterIsCheckedStoryboard" />
              <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ExitIsCheckedStoryboard" />

              <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard BeginTime="0:0:0">
                  ...
                </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>

            <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
              <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                  ...
                </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
            </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
          </MultiTrigger>

          <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                    Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                    Value="3" />
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
              <BeginStoryboard x:Name="EnterIsCheckedStoryboard">
                <Storyboard>
                  ...
                </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>

            <Trigger.ExitActions>
              <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ExitIsCheckedStoryboard">
                <Storyboard>
                  ...
                </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I had difficulty implementing the first suggestion as a RadioButton, where the previous bug would still occur but only in certain situations (could not replicate knowingly). The alternative solution however works like a charm. Thank you for your thorough answer, I now have a way better understanding of how animations and visual states work.